# Bootstrap jumbotron full width and height of window with background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a bootstrap  jumbotron on a website, and I was wondering how I would make it the full width and height of the screen, *or at least touching the nav bar*, as there is a gap between the jumbotron and the navbar.

So far, I have a "container" class inside the "jumbotron" class to make it full width of the screen without rounded corners, but how would I have it so it would be the full width and height of the device's window **until someone scrolls down?**

So far this is what I've got:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
    <center><h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula mauris, iaculis quis tortor eget, ultricies mollis nisi. 
        </p>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Button 1</a>
        <!-- <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">Button 2</a> -->
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

So we have 3 issues here:

#### Remove excess space under navbar

The default bootstrap navbar has a `margin-bottom: 20px`, you want to override that like this:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

#### Make jumbotron full width

[Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) says:

> To make the jumbotron full width, and without rounded corners, place
>   it outside all .containers and instead add a .container within.

So basically:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Make jumbotron full hight

I'm not sure how cleanly this will fit into your project, but you can try something like:

```
.jumbotron{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

*A good-to-know: The `vh` stands for `viewport height`

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using the jumbotron just beneath the navbar. You should use the jumbotron inside a container or div, with its class as:

```
<div class="container-full-bg">
```

Using 'full-bg' will increase the width of jumbotron to fit the page. In order to increase the height, I used the text within the container class or simply used `<br>` tags to increase the jumbotron height accordingly per my needs. A sample:

```
<div class="container-full-bg">  <!--  increased the jumbotron width -->
        <div class="jumbotron ">
            <div class="container">
              <br><br><br>
              <p> Write here <p>
              <br><br><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now to display the image properly in the jumbotron, use background-size as cover,customizing the css file as:

```
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url(show-copy.jpg) ;
    background-size: cover; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="height:100vh;"></div>
```

This should give you a full width and full height jumbotron

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with this recently and nothing helped for a while.
The jumbotron left a space at the button and the image didn't reach the footer.

This solution was close but didn't work on some pages

```
    .jumbotron {
      height: 100vh;
      ...
    }
```

so I found this simple solution:

```
    .jumbotron {
      min-height: 100vh;
      ...
    }
```

I hope this helps some people

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you are trying here. I know this thread is a bit old, but....

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
```

would make the jumbotron full width.

Comment: This is not a valid solution.jumbotron-fluid makes it full width and not full height like the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

It is fully achieveable without custom css using just two css classes

```html
<div class="jumbotron vh-100 mb-0">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Your jumbotron here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

`mb-0` is only required if you only have jumbotron and don't want scroll bar to appear.

`vh-100` means viewport height 100% and `mb-0` means margin botton 0

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/